# Locking an Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am tracking travel times and part of that is 10-day averages.  So I have the formula: =sum(a4:a13)/count(a4:a13) - and then a5:a14, a6:15, etc.

When I create new rows at the top, I find that my calculations have changed to =a4:a4 (11 rows).

What I think I need to do is =sum(a"row":a"row+10")/count(a"row":a"row+10")

I suspect this will turn out to be easy, but my Google searching ability has failed me so I'm hoping someone can help or point me to an existing answer.

Thank you!

Comment: Did my answer work for you. This site thrives on feedback. If it worked please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer. If it did not work please let me know what went wrong so I can better the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX:

The following will give you a static A4:A13:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,4):INDEX(A:A,13))
```

You can do the same in the COUNT.

To make it more dynamic you can use Row and some math:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:A,ROW()):INDEX(A:A,ROW()+10))
```

This will reference the row in which the formula is found and create a range that is from that row to a row 10 cells down.

Comment: Thanks, Scott - that was indeed it.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @JamesLamb please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.